# Save/Export saved shortcuts/webapps from Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts, web-application, progressive-web-app

In Chrome-based browsers there is an option to make a shortcut as new tab from any URL and open those urls like a web app. My question is: is there any way to save/export those and load/import them in a new install?

There is a Chrome Apps folder which contains shortcuts but they lead to

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome_proxy.exe"  --profile-directory=Default --app-id=APP-ID-HERE"
```

I found this APP-ID folder in two places:

```
C:\...\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Applications\_crx_APP-ID-HERE\
 
C:\...\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Applications\Manifest Resources\APP-ID-HERE\
```

Obviously the copy-paste method does not work :D

I would appreciate any idea about this.